# Windows batch file: Referencing varible in for loop doesn't work properly

Tags: windows, batch-file

When I try to reference this variable in my for loop, it doesn't reference the value correctly. It stays at the value it was set before the loop. I tested that.
But it seems that it updates the variable, though. Which makes even less sense to me. I debugged the variable with the "set" command in the loop. And yes, the value updates, but referencing it in the for loop still results in the value.

```
set /a index=0
for %%f in (*.*) do ( 
    set /a index=index+1
    echo index: %index%
)
echo index: %index%`
```

console output:

```
index: 0
index: 0
index: 0
index: 0
index: 0
index: 0
index: 0
index: 0
index: 0
index: 0
index: 0
index: 0
index: 12
```

Comment: This question has been asked a multitude of times, basically on a daily base. Please use the search function to research your problem before posting duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

That's well documented behaviour in batch files with parenthesized blocks in `for`. The reason is that the value is evaluated at the parsing phase of the batch file.

To change the value of a variable inside a block, you need to either

1. **enable delayed expansion**

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a index=0 
for %%f in (*.*) do (  
  set /a index+=1 
  echo index: !index! 
) 
echo final: !index!
```

or

2. use a **call** to a subroutine to set the variable.

```
@echo off
set /a index=0 
for %%f in (*.*) do call :incindex
echo final: %index%
goto :eof

:incindex
set /a index+=1
echo %index%
goto :eof
```

Comment: _"That's well documented behaviour in batch files with blocks in for"_ Not quite in `for` blocks only, it is the case in any parenthesized block...

Comment: yep, a missing word, corrected.

Comment: What I am saying is that it is not only `for` parenthesized block, any parenthesized block is affected. So remove `for` from that statement.

Comment: I know, but in this specific question, the problem appears in the parenthesized block of after the for.